# Passing values to job executor pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have in transformation write data to Table output

[image]

In next step I have transformation where I have job executor with shell script
How can i pass value from table input to job executor to make it execute for all data in table. e.g.
script:

```
ls "value1_from_table_input"
```

write to log

and next run

```
ls "value2_from_table_input"
```

write to log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the "*shell for every row*" directory in the samples/jobs directory of your Pentaho installation.
The keys to make it work, is in the transformation you use the "*Copy rows to results*" step, and in the job, when adding the "*Shell*" job entry, you check the "*Copy previous results to args?*" and the "*Execute for every input row*"